# Go - accepting http post multipart file(s)

Tags: http, post, go, multipart

I am trying to figure out how to accept/receive a HTTP Post in Go. I just want to be able to receive a file, grab its mime-type and save the file locally.

I've been searching all day but all I can find is how to send a file to some remote location but none of the examples I find cover receiving it.

Any help would be appreciated.

using Justinas' example and mixing with my existing experiment I've gotten this far but m.Post never seems to be called.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "github.com/codegangsta/martini"
    "github.com/codegangsta/martini-contrib/render"
)

func main() {

    m := martini.Classic()

    m.Use(render.Renderer(render.Options{
        Directory: "templates", // Specify what path to load the templates from.
        Layout: "layout", // Specify a layout template. Layouts can call {{ yield }} to render the current template.
        Charset: "UTF-8", // Sets encoding for json and html content-types.
    }))


    m.Get("/", func(r render.Render) {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", "g./")
        r.HTML(200, "hello", "world")
    })

    m.Get("/:who", func(args martini.Params, r render.Render) {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", "g./:who")
        r.HTML(200, "hello", args["who"])
    })

    m.Post("/up", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", "p./up")

        file, header, err := r.FormFile("file")
        defer file.Close()

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
            return
        }

        out, err := os.Create("/tmp/file")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "Failed to open the file for writing")
            return
        }
        defer out.Close()
        _, err = io.Copy(out, file)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
        }

        // the header contains useful info, like the original file name
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "File %s uploaded successfully.", header.Filename)
    })

    m.Run()
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go's `net/http` server handles this pretty, using `mime/multipart` package behind the scenes. You only need to call `r.FormFile()` on your `*http.Request` to get a [multipart.File](http://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#File) back.

[Here's a complete example](http://play.golang.org/p/MrE9BwNbB1). And the result of uploading a file with curl:

```
justinas@ubuntu /tmp curl -i -F file=@/tmp/stuff.txt http://127.0.0.1:8080/
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 24 Dec 2013 20:56:07 GMT
Content-Length: 37
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

File stuff.txt uploaded successfully.%                                                                                              
justinas@ubuntu /tmp cat file
kittens!
```

Comment: thank you, i'll check this out. i'm sure it will work as i recognize your name from some of the other examples/github that i've been reading.

Comment: i've updated the original question with my existing code and your code. any suggestions as to what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Your example [works for me](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0eVVWjyU) (using curl, again). There could be an issue in your HTML form and not in the Go handler. For one, a common issue is forgetting to set the correct `enctype` ([multipart/form-data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)).

Comment: Thank you! Turns out the problem wasnt with Go, it was with nginx' max upload file size. changed it to 50MB and good sailing.